# Amanzon SNS confirmed subscription expiration

Tags: amazon-sns

What happens to SNS topic subscriptions that have been confirmed and then abandoned and not explicitly unsubscribed?  Is there some expiration time that can be set?  I didn't see anything about this in the documentation.  It's possible that I could collected a lot of garbage subscriptions for the topic if I have a lot of abandoned clients.

You may be wondering why I'd ask such as question.

I'm wondering about this as I'm working on something that requires publish-subscribe behavior and I could have dangling subscriptions that I would like to manage.  It could be a large number of dangling subscriptions - like thousands.  I don't control the client code so I can't guarantee that they will be well-behaved and they may just "disappear" from the network and never get a chance to unsubscribe even if they were well-behaved.

Is there some best-practice hygiene for this?

I could periodically schwack all the existing subscriptions (as the topic owner) and the clients listening to topic traffic would have to resubscribe from time to time, but that is not a good path IMHO.  It would leave perhaps critical gaps in topic traffic to legitimate listeners and also levy a "re-subscribe" requirement on them I would prefer not to.

Maybe I'm just being dumb.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you come up with as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There really is no auto unsubscribe option once you subscribe. The best way is to maintain the list of topics that you are interested in at any time. If Any other topic outside that list sends you a notification then just unsubscribe to that topic with the unsubscribe url provided in the request sent to you.